# Postgres wanting string to be date

Tags: postgresql

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Ships (name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, launched DATE);
CREATE TABLE Battles (name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, battledate DATE);
```

Now when I try to do this:

```
SELECT launched FROM Ships WHERE name='ship_one' > (SELECT battledate FROM Battles WHERE name='battle_one');
```

it triggers this:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "ship_one"
```

but name is supposed to be a string, not a date.

```
SELECT launched FROM Ships WHERE name='ship_one';
```

works fine

```
SELECT now() > (SELECT battledate FROM Battles WHERE name='battle_one');
```

works fine as well (outputs f for false)

can anyone figure out what the problem is here?

when I try

```
(SELECT launched FROM Ships WHERE name='ship_one') > (SELECT battledate FROM Battles WHERE name='battle_one');
```

it returns

```
syntax error at or near ">"
```

Comment: `WHERE name='ship_one' > 09/13/2014;` ... this is what your query tries to do. It compares a string with a date. It can't do that so it's giving you an error. You should rethink what do you want to compare and according to this select the correct column inside your sub select.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing conditions
This is one condition

```
SELECT launched FROM Ships WHERE name='ship_one'
```

And this seems to be another condition.

```
> (SELECT battledate FROM Battles WHERE name='battle_one');
```

You are trying to mix and boolean condition (name = 'ship_one' which returns a boolean) with a date.

```
SELECT launched FROM Ships WHERE name='ship_one' **AND** somedate > (SELECT battledate FROM Battles WHERE name='battle_one');
```

Comment: no, launched is supposed to be a date. that would not be what I want because I'm trying to compare "launched" and the second part of the query, both of which are dates.

Comment: well. then you need to do something like select 1 where (select launched from ships where name = 'ship_one') > (select batledate from battle where name = 'battle_one')

Answer (score 1):

Got it

```
select (select launched from ships where name = 'ship_one') > (select battledate from battles where name = 'battle_one');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 WHERE name='ship_one' > (SELECT battledate FROM Battles WHERE name='battle_one');
```

reduces to:

```
 (boolean) > battledate                   (error)
```

probably want:

```
where name='ship one' and something??? > battledate
```